# How to copy ID3D11Texture2D content to IMFSample on win7?

Tags: c++, video, ms-media-foundation, direct3d11

In win8 and above, I can directly use MFCreateDXGISurfaceBufferWrapper, but On Win7 system does not support this interface, so I can only copy it on the CPU ("_capture_texture_2D" was created on Win7 with D3D11_USAGE_STAGING) But the final image displayed is slanting. I feel that the length or width of the conversion result is not correct:

- _capture_texture2d is created for d2d-interoperability with DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, but MFVideoFormat_XXX did not see the corresponding format
- Maybe "Lock" needs pitch support, but I can't find the introduce

  ```
   HRESULT hr = E_NOTIMPL;
   CComPtr<IMFMediaBuffer> media_buffer;
   if (IsWindows8OrGreater())
   {
       hr = MFCreateDXGISurfaceBufferWrapper(__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), _capture_texture2d, 0, FALSE, &media_buffer);

       CComPtr<IMF2DBuffer> twod_buffer;
       hr = media_buffer->QueryInterface(&twod_buffer);
       RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

       DWORD length = 0;
       hr = twod_buffer->GetContiguousLength(&length);
       RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

       hr = media_buffer->SetCurrentLength(length);
       RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);
   }
   else
   {
       D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
       _capture_texture2d->GetDesc(&desc);

       UINT32 img_size = 0;
       hr = MFCalculateImageSize(MFVideoFormat_RGB32, desc.Width, desc.Height, &img_size);
       RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

       D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE resource;
       UINT subresource = D3D11CalcSubresource(0, 0, 0);
       hr = immediate_context->Map(_capture_texture2d, subresource, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &resource);
       RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

       hr = MFCreateMemoryBuffer(img_size, &media_buffer);
       if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
       {
           BYTE *dst = NULL;
           hr = media_buffer->Lock(&dst, NULL, NULL);
           if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
           {
               BYTE* src = (BYTE*)resource.pData;
               for (size_t i = 0; i < desc.Height; i++)
               {
                   memcpy(dst, src, desc.Width * 4);
                   src += resource.RowPitch;
                   dst += desc.Width * 4;
               }

               media_buffer->Unlock();
           }
       }

       immediate_context->Unmap(_capture_texture2d, subresource);
       RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

       hr = media_buffer->SetCurrentLength(img_size);
   }   
   RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

   CComPtr<IMFSample> sample;
   hr = MFCreateSample(sample);
   RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

   hr = sample->AddBuffer(media_buffer);
   RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

use function MFGetStrideForBitmapInfoHeader and MFCopyImage solve:

```
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
    _capture_texture2d->GetDesc(&desc);

    UINT32 img_size = 0;
    GUID dst_format = MFVideoFormat_RGB32;
    hr = MFCalculateImageSize(dst_format, desc.Width, desc.Height, &img_size);
    RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

    LONG dst_stride = 0;
    hr = MFGetStrideForBitmapInfoHeader(dst_format.Data1, desc.Width, &dst_stride);
    RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE resource;
    UINT subresource = D3D11CalcSubresource(0, 0, 0);
    hr = immediate_context->Map(_capture_texture2d, subresource, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &resource);
    RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

    hr = MFCreateMemoryBuffer(img_size, &media_buffer);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        BYTE *dst_data = NULL;
        hr = media_buffer->Lock(&dst_data, NULL, NULL);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            if (dst_stride >= 0)
            {
                hr = MFCopyImage(dst_data, dst_stride, (BYTE*)resource.pData, resource.RowPitch, desc.Width * 4, desc.Height);
            }
            else
            {
                BYTE *src_ptr = (BYTE*)resource.pData;
                BYTE *dst_ptr = dst_data - dst_stride * (desc.Height - 1);
                size_t copy_bytes = min(resource.RowPitch, (UINT)-dst_stride);
                for (size_t i = 0; i < desc.Height; i++)
                {
                    memcpy(dst_ptr, src_ptr, copy_bytes);

                    src_ptr += resource.RowPitch;
                    dst_ptr += dst_stride; 
                }
            }

            media_buffer->SetCurrentLength(img_size);

            media_buffer->Unlock();
        }
    }

    immediate_context->Unmap(_capture_texture2d, subresource);

    ...
```