# E_INVALIDARG when I encode the NV12 texture?

Tags: video, direct3d, ms-media-foundation, dxgi, desktop-duplication

I am converting RGB to NV12 and encode it to H264.

- get desktop frame which is RGB(done)
- convert it to NV12 using VideoProcessor(done,I have test the NV12 texture and it is right)
- ProcessInput to IMFTransform(it returns S_OK but I donot know if it goes ok)
- can not get the right result.(E_INVALIDARG)

Comment: MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT means the encoder is waiting for another call to  ProcessInput, ie: it won't output anything until you feed more data because it cannot build any valid frame in its current state

Comment: Please don’t link to code.  Instead, type it into the question body.

Comment: @DanielWalker since when this is better?

Comment: CLSID_CMSH264EncoderMFT doesn't support MFT_MESSAGE_SET_D3D_MANAGER PS: you should check for all errors. Where do you get E_INVALIDARG?

Comment: I don't get any E_INVALIDARG here but I get 100% E_FAIL from ConvertToContiguousBuffer (Roman explained why I believe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not too far from being able to work, but there are a few problems.

First, I could not reproduce the claimed E_INVALIDARG with the code as it is.

Second, you hardcode H.264/AVC encoder to encode 1920x1080@30 video. You don't check the effectively selected input media type, in particular, assuming that encoder sorts things out from partial media type. You would normally not want to let it work this way and specify the media types explicitly or at least make sure that they get resolved as you expect it.

Third, most important, your texture, `desc` you feed into `ProcessInput` has resolution of display - not the resolution configured with the encoder - you can't expect it to work like this; then you attach hardcoded value with `SetCurrentLength` (don't do this - you need some thing [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64556784/868014) from the body of the Q), then feed this into encoder with hardcoded resolution.

Fourth, note that you are using software video encoder, and hence you don't really have an advantage of using video memory backed input. It is not the problem here, just a side observation.

---

I updated your code to make it work. It is far from being perfect, but it does what you wanted it to do.

https://github.com/roman380/MediaFoundationDesktopToNv12Avc/blob/main/sandbox.cpp

It creates "C:\Temp\Output.h264" with raw H.264/AVC content, you can play it with something like [Media Player Classic](https://mpc-hc.org/).

Comment: thank you .first if you run it and wait for seconds you will find the E_INVALIDARG in Thread `Get`  processOutputResult. second I should not spefify the outputMediaType but to getOutputAvailableMediaType? third If I do not `SetCurrentLength` it will never get outputSample. and for the last. what is the hardware video encoder? I am not very clear what you suggest  me to do.

Comment: I have not seen `processOutputResult` to be `E_INVALIDARG`, the code section `if (FAILED(processOutputResult))` is never hit for me. But as I mentioned there are problems with code before this point: you have resolution mismatch in your setup.

Comment: thank you .Should I getOutputAvailableMediaType? to set the  InputMediaType? and how to check the selected inputMediaType? how to assuming the ecoder sorts things out from partial media type?

Comment: There are many ways depending on what exactly you want to reach. From standpoint of smallest code, I would suggest to not hardcode 1920x1080 and instead use monitor resolution across the entire code. As for input media type, either set in explicitly like you crearte output media type, or get media type from MFT and print out details to check yourself. As for setting buffer length, use the code snippet from the Q I linked above to not hardcode.

Comment: you said the texture `desc` has resolution fo display not the resolution configured with the encoder. but I really set the same resolution (encoder input type and the texture is 1920*1080 which is my screen resolution)it is hard to figure out where is wrong.

Comment: First of all, I just saw it with debugger. Second, just hardcode another resolution and you will see it. Third, there is still the question of length, textures might be padded and so it is not accurate to hardcode what you expected them to be, esp. not knowing this for sure.

Comment: [Certified Hardware Encoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/h-264-video-encoder#certified-hardware-encoder). You access available encoders with `MFTEnum`.